# Can I customize existing viewWithTag:(NSInteger) method for stringTag?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview, nsstring, viewwithtag

Please help me, I have been customizing a UIView class to set NSString value as a tag, but how can I get that view from view hierarchy.In UIView class default method to get view is `viewWithTag:(NSInteger)`.

Please see below code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIView (StringTag)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *tagString;
@end

#import "UIView+StringTag.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h> 

static const void *tagKey = &tagKey;

@implementation UIView (StringTag)

- (void)setTagString:(NSString *)tagString
{
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, tagKey, tagString,OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}

- (id)tagString
{
return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, tagKey);
}
@end
```

I want a method like `viewWithStringTag:(NSString *)stringTag`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use recursive search, includes self

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    

@interface UIView (StringTag)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *tagString;    

- (UIView *)viewWithStringTag:(NSString *)strTag;    

@end    

#import "UIView+StringTag.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>     

static const void *tagKey = &tagKey;    

@implementation UIView (StringTag)    

- (void)setTagString:(NSString *)tagString
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, tagKey, tagString,OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}    

- (id)tagString
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, tagKey);
}    

- (UIView *)viewWithStringTag:(NSString *)strTag{
    if ([self.tagString isEqual:strTag]){
        return self;
    }
    if (!self.subviews.count){
        return nil;
    }
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews){
        UIView *targetView = [subview viewWithStringTag:strTag];
        if (targetView){
            return targetView;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}    

@end
```

Here are my testing code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    aView.tagString = @"aView";
    UIView *bView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    bView.tagString = @"bView";
    [self.view addSubview:aView];
    [aView addSubview:bView];

    UIView *targetView = [self.view viewWithStringTag:@"bView"];

    NSLog(@"%@", targetView);
    // <UIView: 0x7f933bc21e50; frame = (0 0; 100 100); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f933bc1c430>>
}
```

Comment: Works fine on my test project. Anything wrong? @Vishu